# Can't click button selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to press a button, but nothing happens. There are no errors when clicking, the element itself is located. Element is visible.

[image]

There is a my code:

```
verify = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Resend email"]')
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(verify).click(verify).perform()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty" style="pointer-events: auto;"><button class="UnstyledLink ButtonLink Flex-flex" type="button"><div class="Box-root Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--baseline Flex-direction--row" style="position: relative;"><div class="TextAligner Box-root" style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; flex: 0 0 auto;"></div>
<div class="Box-root Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--baseline Flex-direction--row Flex-justifyContent--flexStart" style="line-height: 0; flex: 1 1 auto;"><span class="ButtonLink-label Text-color--blue Text-fontSize--14 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--20 Text-numericSpacing--proportional Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--noWrap Text-display--block" style="margin-top: -1px;">
<span>Resend email</span></span></div></div></button></div></div></div>
```

UPD: Solved the problem. If u have same issue try to change browser profile / launch with default options

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Hi DeMurk, have you tried `find_element_by_css_selector`? if not then give it a shot and let us know.

Comment: @Yatin
Hello. I tried this one. ```verify = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class='UnstyledLink ButtonLink Flex-flex']")
verify[0].click()```
This doesn't help too

Comment: Try printing `verify` and see how many elements if has stored. And check if the 0th element is actually the element that you are trying to click

Comment: Also if possible share the link of the site... that way we might try out things too...

Comment: @Yatin
Its only one element in the list. Site is https://stripe.com/

Comment: I have posted an answer. I wouldn't recommend using `elements` when you expect only one element.. sometime you might be clicking on other elements ... always use `element` instead of `elements` if there is only one element

Comment: Also what do you mean by`Also know what 'screenshot_as_base64' shows weird one `? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to click on it... Not sure what is the problem on your side...

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stripe.com/')

#click on Sign-in
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[1]/nav/ul/li[3]/a[2]/span').click()

#send email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys("abc@gmail.com")

#send password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="old-password"]').send_keys("akldjfkajdf")

#click on continue
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/button/div/div[2]/span').click()

#click on skip for now
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/a/span').click()

#click on verify you email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/span').click()

#click on resend email
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/button/div/div[2]/span/span').click()
```

Comment: This is a very crude code. I wouldn't recommend writing long xpaths like this... instead, you should use css_selectors or ids or classes instead. That way a change in the site won't break your code... I just wanted to quickly test stuff so i used xpaths...

Comment: Thank you. I tried ur code, its working. I think its chromedriver issue, cus clicking your xpath on chromedriver still doing nothing :D